# Need help getting the last message from a conversation between two users

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am currently building a messaging feature and my goal is to get the last message between two users (a message inbox). And then when a user clicks on the last message, a full conversation between the two users will show. I currently have a `messages` table with the following data:

```
create table messages(
  message_id serial primary key not null,
  user_id_sender integer,
  user_id_receiver integer,
  subject varchar(100),
  message text,
  seen boolean default false,
  date timestamptz
)
```

My question is, is it better to create a `inbox table` to log the last conversation between two users, or is there a query to find the last message between the two users and display that message with just the messages table. I have looked into and tried using `CTE's`, `triggers` and playing with `SELECT DISTINCT` that other have posted to no avail. I'm using `React` for my front end and get duplicate key issues with left joins with null values. Please I would like to know A.The best way to approach and normalize the data and B. Find the best query that would produce the desired result

Any help would be appreciated I'm just trying to find the right path and the best things to look into and learn to solve this kind of problem.

I have tried using CTEs, triggers, SELECT DISTINCT

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a better option as per your question `is it better to create a xxx table`, then the answer is yes for retrieval of your latest message assuming you are storing only one record with the last message in that table xxx and the same record would be updated with the recent message always. You can update this table in your main table trigger (i.e. `messages` table) and the downside would be little performance hit during the insertion you can take a call on that after you check with a load test.

Coming to your second question `is there a query to find the last message using the messages table`; you can have a subquery to select the MAX of date from the messages table and then use that date in your main query like `date = ( select max(date)` to get the latest message.  Make sure to create an index on the date column and also, for better performance add an additional where clause on the date column (for example date should be greater than the current date minus 30 days) in the main query.